# How to show a div as a popup without any click event in java script?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to **setup a popup with an event listener** rather than using the onclick function. My project is a calender and when I select a day I want it to show a div as pop up.

Comment: Write your question content with the proper subject and reference it is not the way to post a question.

Comment: Pop up while clicking, but not `onclick`?

Comment: You can under on day selected of calender

Comment: Why the css tag? You want a css-only solution?

Comment: Because he want to change the visibility of a div with a js event

Answer (score 0):

This question is pretty basic, checkout [W3School](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_eventlistener.asp).

```
myFunction(){
...
}

var element = document.getElementById("myPopUp");
element.addEventListener("click", myFunction());
```

Comment: Want to show as a pop up nothing more. When I click on days, I will able show div but i want it in pop rather to a div

Comment: Then use alert function? ```alert('this is a pop up');```

Comment: In alert it simply show string as it is but hml as html

Comment: could you be clearer? use [grammarly](https://www.grammarly.com) maybe? You want no html but html, this makes no sense...